# Cygwin: Relocation truncated to fit R_X86_64_32S against '.data'

Tags: assembly, cygwin, linker-errors

I was recently trying to compile the "Find a Maximum Value" program from the book "Programming from the Ground Up". Since I'm using Windows, I compile the assembly file with Cygwin. However, I get the following errors:

```
/tmp/ccuamKmO.o:fake:(.text+0xc): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against `.data'
/tmp/ccuamKmO.o:fake:(.text+0x1d): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against `.data'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It's probably some silly error and I really can't recognise it.
This is the code for the program:

```
.section .data
    data_items: 
        .long 3, 67, 34, 222, 45, 75, 54, 34, 44, 33, 22, 11, 66, 0

.section .text
    .globl main

main:
    jmp find_largest
  ret_find_largest:

    ret

/* 
 * %edi - Holds the index of the item being examined
 * %ebx - Largest item found
 * %eax - Current item
 */
find_largest:
    movl $0, %edi
    movl data_items(,%edi,4), %eax /* load eax with first item */
    movl %eax, %ebx

  start_loop:
    cmpl $0, %eax
    je loop_exit
    incl %edi
    movl data_items(,%edi,4), %eax
    cmpl %ebx, %eax
    jle start_loop
    movl %eax, %ebx
    jmp start_loop

  loop_exit:
    jmp ret_find_largest
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems your assembler code is intended for 32-bit machine but you're assembling for x64. Try adding `-m32` on the command line.

Comment: Compiling with "gcc -m32 cmp.S -o cmp" gives me a huge list of linker errors like these: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for -lgcc_s

Comment: I believe there's a linker option you need to specify as well. Something along the lines of `-mi386pe`. To pass it from GCC you can use `-Wl,-mi386pe`.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Thanks, the option I found is -Wl,-mi386pep. I get the same two errors like in the first post but with some new: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../../../lib/libcygwin.a(libcmain.o): In function `main': /usr/src/debug/cygwin-1.7.25-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/libcmain.c:39: undefined reference to `WinMain'
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-1.7.25-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/libcmain.c:39:(.text.startup+0x7e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `WinMain'

Comment: OK so it seems that this line of code causes the relocation error: movl data_items(,%edi,4), %eax. But shouldn't it be a valid line of code?

Comment: I'm still stuck with this and I'm looking for a solution... Can anybody provide a bit of help?

Answer (score 2):

I faces with this problem. Just try to compile with `gcc -no-pie file.s -o file` 
It worked fine for me. Then `./file` in order to run executable

Comment: Please don't add the [same answer to multiple questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-ad??d-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions). Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates, once you earn enough reputation. If it is not a duplicate, tailor the post to the question

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a Windows error. I had the same one and couldn‘t figure out how to solve it. 
Trying the exact same thing on linux worked.

For x64 and with nasm:

```
nasm -f elf64 -o <asm_name>.o <asm_name>.asm
```

If you’re using a c-program calling it, follow this with:

```
gcc -m64 -o <c_name> <c_name>.c <asm_name>.asm
```

You can finally call this with `./<c_name>`

I know, this is no real solution to your problem, but at least a way it would work.

Comment: It sounds more like you have a question than an answer.  If you get R_X86_64_32S relocation errors on Windows, you'll also get them on Linux if your gcc is configured with `-pie` as the default (like on most recent distros).  [Avoiding 32-bit absolute addressing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50205129) is the obvious solution here, or make a non-PIE executable on Windows.  (Assuming you actually have 64-bit code in the first place, unlike in this question where the 32-bit addressing mode is a clue that it's intended for 32-bit mode.).

Answer (score -1):

When I had this problem the answer was simple, I was trying to compile wrong.

Once I created the object files:
   `gcc -g -O -c main.c functions.c`

I could compile the program:
    `gcc main.o functions.o -o prog`

Sorry, I don't know assembly so I don't know if this is applicable to the OP. Hopefully this helps someone though.

Comment: No, this is not useful at all.  Compiling with the default `-m64` would give this error with this code for many setups, because it's written for 32-bit mode.  And if you had actual 64-bit code that gave this error, this answer isn't helpful.  Also, you don't need to compile to `.o` separately, you can just `gcc -g -O3 -o prog *.c`