# Unable to move variables in .data to registers with Mac x86 Assembly

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, att, relative-addressing

I have written a small piece of assembly with AT&T syntax and have currently declared three variables in the `.data` section. However, when I attempt to move any of those variables to a register, such as `%eax`, an error from `gcc` is raised. The code and error message is below:

```
.data
  x:.int 14
  y:.int 4
  str: .string "some string\n"

.globl _main

_main:
  pushq %rbp
  movq %rsp, %rbp
  subq $16, %rsp
  movl x, %eax; #attempting to move the value of x to %eax;
  leave
  ret
```

The error raised is:

> call_function.s:14:3: error: 32-bit absolute addressing is not supported in 64-bit mode
>
> movl x, %eax;
>
> ^

I have also tried moving the value by first adding the `$` character in front of `x`, however, a `clang` error is raised:

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Does anyone know how the value stored in `x` can be successfully moved to `%eax`? I am using x86 assembly on Mac OSX and compiling with `gcc`.

Comment: Use `movl x(%rip), %eax`.

Comment: @Jester Thank you, `x(%rip)` works! If you could write an answer with an explanation, I will accept it.

Comment: The error message is slightly dishonest.  Yes, `movl x, %eax` is supported by the architecture, but you are not supposed to use it.

Comment: @fuz Why is that?

Comment: @Ajax1234 Because (a) the encoding is a byte longer and (b) `movl x, %eax` uses direct addressing whereas `movl x(%rip), %eax` uses relative addressing.  Direct address makes your code no longer position independent, which is why you should not use it when referring to variables.

Comment: [intel syntax duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47300844/mach-o-64-bit-format-does-not-support-32-bit-absolute-addresses-nasm-accessing)

Comment: @fuz: In AT&T syntax, the `moffs` forms of `mov` (with a 64-bit absolute address) use the `movabs` mnemonic, so plain `mov` implies you want the `mov r32, r/m32` opcode with a ModR/M byte.  The MachO64 output format doesn't support 32-bit absolute relocations at all, and the image base address is above 2^32 on OS X so a `[disp32]` addressing mode can't work.  Thus for `mov`, RIP-relative is the only option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**A RIP-relative addressing mode is the only good option for addressing static data on MacOS**; the image base address is above 2^32 so 32-bit absolute addresses aren't usable even in position-dependent code (unlike x86-64 Linux).  RIP-relative addressing of static data is position-independent, so it works even in position-independent executables (ASLR) and libraries.

**`movl x(%rip), %eax`** is the AT&T syntax for RIP-relative.

**`mov eax, dword ptr [rip+x]`** in GAS `.intel_syntax noprefix`.

Or, to get the address of a symbol into a register, **`lea x(%rip), %rdi`**

---

NASM syntax: `mov eax, [rel x]`, or use `default rel` so `[x]` is RIP-relative.

See [Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses. NASM Accessing Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47300844/mach-o-64-bit-format-does-not-support-32-bit-absolute-addresses-nasm-accessing) for more background on what you *can* do on OS X, e.g. `movabs x, %eax` would be possible because the destination register is AL/AX/EAX/RAX.  (64-bit absolute address, but don't do that because it's larger and not faster than a RIP-relative load.)

See also http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html.

Comment: Does this mean that in the GNU assembler, for something like `movq x, %rdx`, a label `x` is treated as `m32` even when building 64-bit code?

Comment: @c-x-berger: no, `m32` in Intel's manuals means 32-bit operand-size.  It implies nothing about which addressing mode is used to reach those 4 bytes of memory.  `movq x, %rdx` is an `m64` memory operand to match the `q` operand-size and the 64-bit destination register, but you told it not to use RIP-relative, and you didn't use `movabs` for a 64-bit absolute address (only available for an RAX destination anyway), so the assembler has to encode the address in a Mod/RM byte.  The only non-RIP-relative mode that doesn't include any other registers is `[sign-extended-disp32]`