# AT&T syntax hello world works but intel syntax does not

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler, intel-syntax

I am writing a hello world program for linux x86_64 using GAS assembler and here is my code in AT&T syntax.

```
#.intel_syntax noprefix

.section .data
    msg:
        .ascii "hello world\n"
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
    movq  $1, %rax
    movq  $1, %rdi
    movq  $msg, %rsi
    movq  $12, %rdx
    syscall

    movq  $60, %rax
    movq  $0, %rdi
    syscall
```

This works and prints "hello world". Here is intel syntax:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

.section .data
    msg:
        .ascii "hello world\n"
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, msg
    mov rdx, 12
    syscall

    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

This compiles and runs fine but does not print "hello world". I am assuming the mistake is in `mov rsi, msg`? If so, what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `mov rsi, offset msg`.  gas uses a masm-like syntax where `mov rsi, msg` moves the content of `msg` to `rsi` instead of moving the address.  The `offset` keyword has to be used to avoid this issue.

If you want to program in Intel syntax, I advise you to pick a better assembler like nasm.

Comment: @WingerSendon Note that you need go back to your original code and fix some of the directives for it to assemble on nasm, but the syntax is overall much saner than with gcc in Intel syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an AT&T syntax disassembler (like `objdump -d`)  to see that `mov rsi, msg` in GAS `.intel_syntax` assembles to `mov msg, %rsi`, a 64-bit load from a 32-bit-absolute address.

Or use `objdump -d -Mintel` to see Intel-syntax disassembly for your working version.

GDB has `set disassembly-flavor intel` or att, so you can flip even within one debugging session.

---

And BTW, you should use RIP-relative LEA to get 64-bit static addresses into registers.  It's more efficient than `mov r64, imm64`

```
lea   msg(%rip), %rsi    # AT&T

lea   rsi, [msg + rip]  # GAS .intel_syntax

lea   rsi, [rel msg]     ; NASM
```

(but less efficient than `mov r32, imm32` in a position-dependent executable where static labels are in the low 31 bits of virtual address space.)

```
 ## In x86-64 position-dependent executables on Linux

 mov  $msg, %esi            # AT&T

 mov   esi, OFFSET msg      # GAS .intel_syntax

 mov   esi, msg          ; NASM
```

Note that OS X puts static addresses outside the low 32, so you even in an executable your addresses are 64-bit. [Unable to move variables in .data to registers with Mac x86 Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50205129/unable-to-move-variables-in-data-to-registers-with-mac-x86-assembly)